# Canvas pixels to opengles coordinates

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am getting problem in finding opengles 3d coordinates of the screen. I searched a lot but I didn’t get any exact solution for that. I can find the touched pixels of the screen using (event.getX() and event.getY()). But I want the 3d coordintes of the screen.  I follow the rajawali(https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali) library for making livewallpaper in opengl.

Here is my code for placing that colorful fish, i am just putting code that i use for drawing that colorful fish :-

```
 final Bitmap generatedBitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(128, 128,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
 Bitmap colorful_fish = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),R.drawable.colorful_fish);

// Create a canvas to do the drawing
final Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas(generatedBitmap2);
//canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
canvas2.drawBitmap(colorful_fish, 0, 0, null);
 final SimpleMaterial simpleMaterial2 = new SimpleMaterial();
 simpleMaterial2.addTexture(mTextureManager.addTexture(generatedBitmap2));
 largeCanvasPlane2 = new Plane(1, 1, 1, 1);
 largeCanvasPlane2.setTransparent(true);
 largeCanvasPlane2.setScale(.2f);
 **largeCanvasPlane2.setPosition(.2f, -.5f,0f);**
 largeCanvasPlane2.setMaterial(simpleMaterial2);
 addChild(largeCanvasPlane2);
```

As i toast the pixels values on touch but i need 3d coordinates.

```
@Override
public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+event.getX()+"   "+event.getY(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are returning X and Y which are 2D coordinates and for 3D coordinates you need X, Y, Z. So you want want 3D coordinates on the screen, get the value of Z to your Toast or other wise you are just returning 2D coords.

Comment: yea how to get 3D coordinates

Comment: I also have same problem. This library does not provide methods which will convert Screen Point to World Point. At least I couldn't find it. The only solution is, I think, to multiple screen coordinates to projection matrix.